# On the elliptic curve $X^3 + 6\cdot 163^2 X - 7\cdot 163^3 = Y^2$ and others

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conic-sections, elliptic-curves, quadratic-forms

**I. Ellipse**

Given the general equation,

$$a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (c + m)^3$$

Let,

\begin{align}
c &= (n + 1)(a - m) + n b\\
a &= p + q + m + 4 m n + 3 m n^2\\ 
b &= p - q + 2 m n + 3 m n^2
\end{align}

and after removing a trivial factor, it becomes the simple *ellipse* centered at the origin,

$$p^2 + 3 q^2 = d$$

where $d = 3m^2 n(n+1) (3 n^2 + 3n + 1).$ For example, the ellipse $p^2+3q^2-7=0$.

[image]

Choose some desired $d$ with integer $(p,q)$. Thus we need to solve for $m$,

$$m = d\,\sqrt{\frac1{3d n(n+1) (3 n^2 + 3n + 1)}}$$

and find rational $n$ such that $m$ is also rational. Assume prime $d=1\,(\text{mod}\,6)$, or [Euler's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eulers6nPlus1Theorem.html), say $d=p^2+3q^2=7$ so $(p,q) = (2,1)$. Then one solution is $n = 1/3,\, m = 3/2$. Substituting $(p,q,m,n)$ into the expressions for $(a,b,c)$, we find,

$$\left(\frac{42}{6}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{15}{6}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{49}{6}\right)^3=\left(\frac{49}{6}+\frac{3}{2}\right)^3$$

---

**II. Elliptic curve**

Here's the difficult part: Characterize which prime $d=p^2+3q^2$ such that the quartic in $n$ to be made a square is solvable,

$$3d n(n+1) (3 n^2 + 3n + 1) = w^2$$

with $w\neq 0$. After some correspondence with S. Tomita, we find this is birationally equivalent to a cubic in $X$ to be made a square,

$$X^3 + 6d^2 X - 7d^3 = Y^2$$

or an *elliptic curve*. The primes of form $d=1\,(\text{mod}\,6) = p^2+3q^2$ are given by [A002476](https://oeis.org/A002476). From that, I tested 150 primes with $d<2024$ using the online Magma calculator and found a LOT had rank $r > 0$ including $d = 163$. There were only 26 with rank $r=0$, namely,

$$73, 97, 193, 241, 337, 409, 457, 601, 673, 769, 937, 1009, 1033, 1129, 1153, \ 1201, 1249, 1297, 1321, 1489, 1609, 1753, 1777, 1801, 1873, 2017$$

so cannot be used for a non-trivial solution to $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = (c + m)^3$. It can be observed they are a **subset** of [A107008](https://oeis.org/A107008), the primes of form $u^2+72v^2.$

***Update***: Based on the Magma code in the answer below, the observation is apparently true for $d<40000$.

---

**III. Question**

**Conjecture 1:** Given the elliptic curve $X^3 + 6d^2 X - 7d^3 = Y^2$ with prime $d = p^2+3q^2$, then a necessary (but not sufficient) condition that it has rank $r=0$ is it is a subset of $d = u^2+72v^2$. (Only a subset since $\color{red}{313} =u^2+72v^2$ has rank $r = 2$.)

**Conjecture 2:** For those special $d = u^2+72v^2$ with rank $r=2$, then a necessary (but not sufficient) condition is it is a subset of $d = x^2+144y^2$. (Only a subset since $193=x^2+144y^2$ has rank $r = 0$.) For $d < 10009$, there are only 22,

$$\color{red}{313}, 433, 577, 1657, 1993, 2137, 3529, 3697, 4057, 4129, 4297, 4513, 4801, 6529, 6553, 7057, 8089, 8209, 8641, 9241, 9337, 9601$$

**all** of which have form $x^2+144y^2.$ If conjectures are not true, then what are the first counter-examples?

*Note*: Can someone test $d=1471$? Magma says it has rank $r=1$, but seems unable to give a generator.

Comment: For $1471$ you can use Heegner points, or (as I did) use the 8-descent functionality in Magma with point searching to find the generator (yes, this is the smallest height point) $(\frac{19932222201317562225012375257481742424559731063967935728045506496459}{8467362711288822222104702085767597142812540237238297969758400841},
\frac{113781428959350936104073806116878025584522454434838239364098710785940894873461652869528448803940229486}{779152100246492921306788146492549903225124915399485595294120147540019237359975052180075509575611})$

Comment: For the first question, I haven't thought about it, but $(d, 0)$ is a $2$-torsion point on $E$. It's likely that if such an obstruction exists, then it will be revealed by a by-hand $2$-isogeny descent (following e.g., Cassel's lecture on elliptic curves).

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Those are huge numbers! No wonder Magma couldn’t find it using the short command i used. Does Magma have a functionality where you input a list of $d$ and Magma outputs the rank? It is so tedious to do it one at a time.

Comment: My honest guess for your second conjecture is that the rank must always be even for parity reasons, but could be $4$ (you might just have to wait a long time for $4$)

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I updated the post with your result and relaxed Conjecture 2 somewhat. And I tested all primes $d=x^2+144y^2<25000$
 with online Magma (which has a limit of 120 seconds). Within that time limit, Magma found all have rank either $r=0$ or $r=2$, consistent with Conjecture 2. But it couldn't give an answer for six primes, namely (11953, 12889, 13441, 14401, 15241, 17881). Do you have a clever way to determine if these have even rank as well?

Comment: @Tito, Magma says E has rank $0$ for $d=11953$ using AnalyticRank() command below.
d := $11953;$
E := EllipticCurve([$6*d^2, -7*d^3$]);
AnalyticRank(E)
According to [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123813/inequality-relating-rank-and-analytic-rank?rq=1),it seems correct.

Comment: @Tomita Thanks, I was checking if there was a rank 4 using $d = x^2+144y^2$.

Comment: @Tomita Using AnalyticRank(E), I tested all 6 primes, and all seems to have rank $0$.

Comment: @Tito If you want to seriously investigate these questions I suggest you learn how to use the higher descent functionality which has been implemented in Magma (and the Cassels-Tate things too, if you want to be fancy). It is all well documented http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/1517. In the $d = 11953$ case naively asking Magma grinds to a hold because Sha has an element of order $4$ (and `Rank` will not call 8-descent by default). My answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4329164/801393 has some details about how one might use this

Answer (score 1):

The last question I answered in my comments, but I may as well give more details here. It is a usual thing that it is hard to find points when you have rank. Since the curve in question (where $d = 1471$) has rank $1$ one could use the Heegner point machinery (`HeegnerPoint` in Magma).

Alternatively (and as we do in practice in cases with higher rank) we can do a higher descent (higher descent -> point has smaller height -> easier to find). In this case, we have a $2$-torsion point, so $2$, $4$, and $8$-descent will be easier than the generic case.

```
d := 1471;
E := EllipticCurve([6*d^2, -7*d^3]);
C,_ := TwoDescent(E : RemoveTorsion:=true);
assert #C eq 1; 
C := C[1]; //2-covering of E which we conjecture has a point

D := FourDescent(C : RemoveTorsion:=true);
D := D[1];
E_prime, psi := AssociatedEllipticCurve(D);
assert E_prime eq E; //could in principle be a different model

eight_covs, phis := EightDescent(D);
pts := [];
for i in [1..#eight_covs] do
    cov := eight_covs[i]; phi := phis[i];
    new := PointSearch(cov, 1000);
    pts := pts cat [psi(phi(P)) : P in new];
end for;

gens := Saturation(pts);
Sprintf("Generators are:\n  T = %o \n  P = %o", gens[1], gens[2]);
```

---

Edit:
Some more sophisticated searching code for the first conjecture.

```
bound := 200;
dd := {p^2 + 3*q^2 : p,q in [1..bound] | IsPrime(p^2 + 3*q^2)};
dd := [d : d in dd];
Sort(~dd);

sub_seq := {p^2 + 72*q^2 : p,q in [1..4*bound]};

rk_0 := [];

for d in dd do
    E := EllipticCurve([6*d^2, -7*d^3]);
    covs := TwoDescent(E : RemoveTorsion:=true);
    pairs := [<C,D,CasselsTatePairing(C,D)> : C,D in covs];
    to_remove := [];
    for p in [x : x in pairs | x[3] eq 1] do
        Append(~to_remove, p[1]);
        Append(~to_remove, p[2]);
    end for;
    filter := [c : c in covs | not c in to_remove];
    if #filter eq 0 then
        Append(~rk_0, <d, d in sub_seq>);
    end if;
end for;

[x : x in rk_0 | x[2] eq false];
```

And some better code for the second one

````
dd := {p^2 + 72*q^2 : p,q in [1..80] | IsPrime(p^2 + 72*q^2)};
dd := [d : d in dd];
Sort(~dd);

rk_non_0 := [];

for d in dd do
    E := EllipticCurve([6*d^2, -7*d^3]);
    covs := TwoDescent(E : RemoveTorsion:=true);
    if #covs ne 0 then
        pairs := [<C,D,CasselsTatePairing(C,D)> : C,D in covs];
        to_remove := [];
        for p in [x : x in pairs | x[3] eq 1] do
            Append(~to_remove, p[1]);
            Append(~to_remove, p[2]);
        end for;
        filter := [c : c in covs | not c in to_remove];
        if #filter ne 0 then
            _,rk_conj := IsPower(#filter + 1, 2);
            Append(~rk_non_0, <d, rk_conj>);
        end if;
    end if;
end for;

rk_non_0;
```
````

Comment: Wait, my question/conjecture was that a necessary (but not sufficient) condition for it to have rank $r=0$ is that $d = x^2+72y^2$. I tested $d=3313$ with Magma and it has rank $r=0$ and $3313 = x^2+72y^2$ with $(x,y) = (55,2)$. So how is it a counter-example?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my code has a brain-typo with the range I allow only being $x,y \leq 50$. Ok, in a much bigger range there appear to be no counterexamples, sorry.

Comment: Mummy, you worried me for a moment.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. My answer is now not an answer, but I've updated with some code I was trying to use to falsify (it's a bit more efficient than just using `Rank` or `AnalyticRank`)

Comment: At least the two conjectures stand for now. Let's see if someone can prove them, or provide a counter-example.

Comment: My bound for Conjecture 1 is $d<2024$. Can you use your code to increase the bound? The new limit can then be added to your answer. (I'm new to Magma and the subtleties of its coding.)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Well using the above code you can check your bound is true for every $d < 200^2$ (under the assumption that there is no $4$-torsion in sha in every such example)

Comment: Ah, so Conjecture 1 is true for all $d < 40000$? That is a vast improvement from my bound of $d < 2024$. Thanks.